# Performance of query against column level dependencies much faster when using deprecated system view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, system-tables

Consider these two queries that get the names of triggers dependant on the `JV_VoyageFlight` column in table `dbo.JobVoyage`.

the first uses the 'old' mechanism that is deprecated ([`sys.sql_dependencies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

```
SELECT
    depObj.name
FROM
    sys.sql_dependencies dep
    INNER JOIN sys.tables tab ON tab.object_id = dep.referenced_major_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch ON sch.schema_id = tab.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON col.object_id = dep.referenced_major_id AND col.column_id = dep.referenced_minor_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects depObj ON depObj.object_id = dep.object_id
WHERE
    sch.name = 'dbo'
    AND tab.name = 'JobVoyage'
    AND col.name = 'JV_VoyageFlight'
    AND depObj.type = 'TR';
```

The suggested replacement view is [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but this does not contain column level dependencies for non schema bound objects and the documentation advises to use the [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function instead for that.

The second query uses the new mechanism.

```
select distinct name from sys.triggers
cross apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.' + object_name(object_id), 'object')
where 
    parent_Class = 1 
    and Is_Ms_Shipped = 0 
    and referenced_entity_Name = 'JobVoyage'
    and referenced_minor_name = 'JV_VoyageFlight'
```

One takes 3 milliseconds. One takes 3000 milliseconds.
Does anyone have a better version of this query to get dependencies out of triggers without using deprecated functionality?

Comment: The first thing I suggest with poorly performing meta-data queries is to [update system table stats](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-system-table-statistics-update/). I can't say if that will improve performance since your comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Personally I hope they keep `sys.sql_dependencies` around. The `is_updated` column [is useful too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46729903/73226). Doesn't look like all use cases have been addressed with the proposed replacements

Comment: It would be interesting to see the execution plan for the 3,000ms version of the query.  If you [edit] that into your question, you may get some more suggestions on how to improve things.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this rewrite that uses a temp table with the new DMF on AdventureWorks2014, and it runs around twice as fast as the version from your question.

```
SELECT t.[object_id], t.[name]
INTO #trigs
FROM sys.triggers t
WHERE 
    t.parent_class = 1 
    and t.is_ms_shipped = 0;

SELECT DISTINCT t.[name] 
FROM #trigs t
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities
(
    'Person.' + object_name(t.[object_id]), 
    'object'
) deps
WHERE 
    deps.referenced_entity_Name = 'Person'
    and deps.referenced_minor_name = 'BusinessEntityID';
```

Here's a screenshot of the Plan Explorer summary after running both queries in the same batch ([plans here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ61E2StI)):

[image: screenshot of plan explorer summary]

The original query (the first row) runs for about 8 ms, the temp table version (the second two rows) varies between 4 and 5 ms.  Of course, your database might have vastly more triggers, objects, and dependencies than AW2014.

As [Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman) mentioned, you may also get some improvements by [updating system table stats](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-system-table-statistics-update/).

---

FYI - those two queries are not exactly equivalent.  The second query will not show the same results if there is a trigger in a different (non-dbo) schema that references `dbo.JobVoyage.JV_VoyageFlight`.

In the example query from my test, there is a trigger in the `Sales` schema (`iduSalesOrderDetail`) that is returned by the deprecated view but not the DMF version, because the column I'm checking for is in the `Person` schema:

[image: screenshot of SSMS results pane showing different results]

If all your objects are in "dbo" then this won't matter, but I thought it was worth pointing out.